# PHP Cookies replace special characters?

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to make an encrypted cookie cause I use public event libraries to my webpage which will receive everything that happens, eg. Receives `$_SESSION`s and `$_COOKIE`'s that is being made. So I want to encrypt my value with my own algorithm, but when I create the cookies some special characters are being changes `+` is changed to `_` which is my problem.

```
<?php
    setcookie( crypto::encrypt("cookieAgreement"), crypto::encrypt("true"), strtotime("+10year") );
    // The encryption will output: QHyRfLOKyNhcViNUharAIZvG02nV4ysTHKASYMyTLhpmkDOFmPn/k8jOOJgGtu++
    // But the cookie made is: QHyRfLOKyNhcViNUharAIZvG02nV4ysTHKASYMyTLhpmkDOFmPn/k8jOOJgGtu__
?>
```

Why is that? Thanks!

**EDIT**: Answer found by OP

setcookie has it's one properties such as the `+` operator, so in order for not trigger an  error it simply replaces the bad `in` operators to something else.

Comment: Just use HTTPS and that will encrypt everything but the URL address.

Comment: I don't want to use SSL encryption

Comment: How will you keep the encryption key secret on the client computer? If you are trying to protect client information you need to be sure the security is correct for their sake.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: @zaph, I know about it

Comment: Anyway the encryption part is off topic of OP's question. The question is why it changes special characters to something else, such as + gets to _

Comment: One possibility is that there are several different Base64 encodings. See [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). You are right, security is not important as long as it is "encrypted".